# I brought uncommitted changes to another branch, now I can't move them back

Tags: git, github-desktop

I'm using Github Desktop because I don't understand git very well.

All I did was change some code in one branch then, without committing my changes, switched to my master branch (bringing along all my uncommitted changes). Now when I try to go back to the original branch with the same uncommitted changes, Github Desktop gives me an error:

"error: you need to resolve your current index first"

I believe it thinks that I'm trying to merge code into my master branch? Although I'm pretty sure I never had uncommitted changes resting in the master branch before hand.

I can see all my changes are in inline in the master branch code but with extra lines like "<<<<<<< Updated upstream" and ">>>>>>> Stashed changes" that surround them.

I'm not sure what do to as I don't want to merge the code like this if that's what it's really asking me to do. I just want to move my changes back to the other branch as if I had never moved them in the first place.

And again, since they are uncommitted changes, I can't just revert. Right?

I don't know what compelled me to bring my changes to the master branch in the first place anyways.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think we might need a bit more info here, however I will continue with some assumptions.

I assume that github desktop did a git stash then changed branch and then popped the stash... but this resulted in a merge conflict, so...
The *first* thing to do is the take a complete copy of the folder containing your repo - back it up. Now we can work safely on your repo and try a few things.

So when the stash pop merge fails (due to conflict) I believe that the stash is not deleted. You can check this by doing: `git log --graph --oneline  --all --decorate` - you should see something like (see the refs/stash):

```
*   edc243c (refs/stash) WIP on test_branch: 85a2f16 added test3   <---- THIS
|\
| * 005e78b index on test_branch: 85a2f16 added test3
|/
* 85a2f16 (test_branch) added test3
```

So, we should have your local changes that where stashed in a separate commit and we can safely undo the merge and go back to your old branch and unstash the changes (if my assumption is correct). So here are the steps:

1. Clear/unstage the merge: `git reset HEAD --hard` (again, make sure you backed up first)
2. Now checkout your original branch `git checkout my_branch`
3. Now unstash your changes: `git stash pop`

Now you should see your modified files appear back, and when you do `git log --graph --oneline  --all --decorate` you will see that the stash has been removed (popped).

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I tried your instructions and didn't get my code back. After popping the stash in the original branch some tiny amount of code popped up that definitely was not changed in that branch before. This is very confusing. My guess is that you're right in that github desktop stashed and moved to master then popped the stash but didn't leave a copy of said stash on the original branch. I have no idea how this code got into the original branch, especially as it's own little stash and I never noticed it before. This tiny popped stash is also complaining about merge conflict!

Comment: I also noticed that this tiny popped stash is all a duplicate of code already in my original branch. It's trying to merge it right on top of duplicate code.

Comment: If anything I think I can just manually fix the problem by copying the conflicting popped stash from master back to the original branch.

Comment: Update: got code back to original condition by carefully copying and pasting.

Comment: @AJUK eghhh.... sounds like github desktop did you a real "solid" there :o ... well, glad you managed to figure it out. To be honest, the amount of learning you may have to do to "tame" tools like github desktop (and other such tools) might be better placed into learning git on the command line (with a few choice aliases) - and then you will not have to deal with this sort of issue and it won't matter where you use it, it will always be the same (barring changes to the newer git API)

Comment: Note: I probably only use about 7-8 commands on an average day (status, fetch, log, checkout, push, merge, pull)...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I stuck to github desktop for a long time since I couldn't get my head around the command line and git in general, even after "learning" it. I just like GUIs more as well. But I'll try to use the cli more. Thanks again!